# Do we have any control over sharding in IPFS?

Tags: ipfs, database, sharding

Suppose I have a huge N-dimensional database and want to store it using IPFS, is there any way I can shard my dataset in such a way that I get N hashes each for single dimension using IPFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own sharding structure using the DAG API. You can learn about it through this examples https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/traverse-ipld-graphs

Answer (score 0):

Additionally see:

> I think we want to use sparse merkle trees
>    https://ethresear.ch/t/data-availability-proof-friendly-state-tree-transitions/1453/6
>   https://github.com/ethereum/research/blob/master/trie_research/bintrie2/new_bintrie.py

https://gitter.im/ethereum/sharding?at=5ad49182102fac7b7b19334c